# Moving nav bar to the right with float

Tags: css

I want the navbar to move to the far right of the screen, but it's not working. I tried applying it to different selectors but nothing changed.

Here is the code https://jsfiddle.net/78f1sw3q

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
    <header class="landing">
        <nav class="main-nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Adopt</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Visit</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.landing{
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
}

.main-nav{
    list-style: none;
}

.main-nav li{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Removing the `width: 100%` fixed it, but I thought `float` needed a `width` in order to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just had to put `float: right;` in `.main-nav`

```css
.landing{
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
}

.main-nav{
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
}

.main-nav li{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
    <header class="landing">
        <nav class="main-nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Adopt</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Visit</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try applying float:right onto main-nav class like so:

```
.main-nav {
    list-style: none;
    float:right;
}
```